# Escaping characters in regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php

The following returns true:

```
$bool1 = preg_match("/5/", "Your bill is $5.00 dude");
var_dump($bool1);
```

I expect this because '5' is in the string.But the following returns false:

```
$bool1 = preg_match("/\$5\./", "Your bill is $5.00 dude");
var_dump($bool1);
```

I thought I was escaping the `$` correctly so that it would look for `$5` in the string and find it, but no. Can someone explain? Thanks.

Comment: preg_quote() can be used for escaping special characters in a regexp; but wrap the regexp in single quotes rather than double quotes, else PHP will do some escaping of its own before it's passed to the regexp parser: `$bool1 = preg_match('/\$5\./', "Your bill is $5.00 dude");`

Comment: It's worth noting that preg_quote just does what he did manually anyway, though. That isn't the source of his problem. Edit: leaving my comment here, but originally everyone was just saying "just use preg_quote", which didn't answer the question.

Comment: @Mike _almost_. preg_quote would have returned `'\$'` and he uses `"\$"` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes to prevent PHP from misinterpreting any escapes:

```
$bool1 = preg_match('/\$5\./', "Your bill is $5.00 dude");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [preg_quote()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function which does proper escaping

Comment: your immediate error is, that you use double-quotes, so slash is firstly used for special-symbol escaping by php itself. you could fix it by using double-slash. but it's just better to always use `preg_quote()` because more complex cases could arise

Answer (score 0):

```
$bool1 = preg_match('/\$5\./', "Your bill is $5.00 dude");
var_dump($bool1);
```